# Scala: how to "preload" content of a lazy Iterator?

Tags: scala, collections, iterator

Let's say I have a lazy Iterator[Item]. The items object are created lazily, only when we iterate the iterator. The items are expensive to create.

I'd like to serialize as a JSON array this iterator. It works (with Jackson scala module) but it seems to me not efficient enough.

As far as I understand, it currently works like this:

- Compute next item
- Serialize item
- Compute next item
- Serialize item
- Compute next item
- Serialize item

I'd like computing of items, and serialization of items, to happen in parallel.

I'd like an Iterator that will start computing a defined amount of next items, when reading next item.

For example I'd like that when doing iterator.next(), behind the scene, the next 50 items get computed, without the iterating thread to be blocked (it should only wait for the next element available).

I've seen the "BufferedIterator" but it is not exactly what I need, as I don't really want to query for "head" explicitly, and I need more than 1 item to preload

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

I am ok for a solution replacing an Iterator with a Stream too, but have a preference for Iterator due to lower memory usage

Comment: Have you tried [GroupedIterator](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator)?

Comment: @laughedelic I'm already using `inputIterator.grouped(chunkSize).map(computeItemsChunk).flatten` so that my items are computed in chunks, but I'm not sure about what you are suggesting

Comment: You say "when doing iterator.next(), behind the scene, the next 50 items get computed". This is what happens with `GroupedIterator`: each time you call `.next`, a new chunk is computed. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: @laughedelic I've rewritten this sentence. Computing the next 50 items is very expensive, and I don't want the iterating thread to be blocked during that time. The computing should happen in another thread, while the iterating thread should only wait for the next item and not the whole item chunk. Do you have any implementation to suggest?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem right, here's an example of what you could do. You could wrap each item computation in a `Future`, so you can iterate over your input stream without blocking and process/serialize each chunk once it's ready. I'm going to do this in REPL and print when each piece is evaluated, so you can see when each thing is happening:

```
@ import concurrent._, ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import concurrent._, ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

@ def futureItem(i: Int): Future[Int] = Future { 
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  println(s"item: ${i}")
  i 
}
defined function futureItem

@ val inputIterator = (1 to 9).toIterator.map(futureItem)
inputIterator: Iterator[Future[Int]] = non-empty iterator
```

So computing each item takes at least 1 second. And now we want to process items in chunks, which also takes some time:

```
@ def computeItemsChunk(items: Seq[Int]): Int = { 
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  val s = items.sum
  println(s"chunk ${items}: ${s}")
  s 
}
defined function computeItemsChunk
```

Now we group input stream, apply [`Future.sequence`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@sequence[A,M[X]<:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,M[A]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[A]]) and compute chunks:

```
@ case object foo {
  val chunksIterator = inputIterator.grouped(3).map { futureItems => 
    Future.sequence(futureItems).map(computeItemsChunk) 
  }
}
defined object foo
```

(I defined it in an object, because otherwise, grouping (or something else) would force evaluation of the first chunk). Now let's see how it is evaluated:

```
@ Await.result(Future.sequence(foo.chunksIterator), Duration.Inf)
item: 2
item: 3
item: 4
item: 1
item: 7
item: 6
chunk List(1, 2, 3): 6
item: 5
item: 8
chunk List(4, 5, 6): 15
item: 9
chunk List(7, 8, 9): 24
res5: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
```

You can see that chunks are computed once the items are available and the iterator advances without waiting for each chunk evaluation.

Comment: Your code is almost what I already use (except I flatten the `Iterator[Iterator[Item]]` at the end. But I had problem in the past with such an implementation, because it takes a single thread per item to process and does too much parallel work and overflow the system. So I compute each chunk of items in parallel, one chunk at a time so that there is at most `chunkSize` parallel computations. Doing too much work at once will actually delay the computing of the first item, and thus the response time of the iterator, and thus my API.

Comment: Notice that I don't need to fold the items into a result like a sum (`computeItemsChunk` should take a `Seq[Id]` and return a `Seq[Item]` for example). If all the computations are started, then it seems to me I don't really need anymore the lazy properties of an Iterator or a Stream, but rather having a `Future[List[Item]]` as a result might be enough

Comment: So the general idea is that I don't want to start all computations at once, and that computations should be triggered only when iterator consumer progress (ie don't load everything at once, but load only the n next items of the iterator, not all the items)

Comment: Well, you can simplify this if you don't need to process groups of items (and you don't need `.grouped` then). But the problem with "too much parallel work" is solvable with tuning the execution context. Which one do you use?

Comment: I still need `grouped` because processing my items in chunks is faster than processing them one by one in parallel (batch processing). I'm currently using the global EC and I'd like to keep it. I must be able to produce multiple iterators at the same time, and I'd like to limit the parallel processing at the iterator level (not global), but without having to create a new EC/threadpool per produced iterator. The thread producing the iterator and passing it to the consumer should never block and be waiting for any processing, and wrapping tasks in Future in a busy EC would block caller thread.

Comment: These are all quite specific requirements and you should add it all to the question (as well as any relevant existing code). I'm not sure if this may help you, but take a look at this project: https://github.com/qifun/stateless-future

Comment: Thanks for trying but I think my question is clear enough: I want 2 threads, one that read in advance N items in my iterator, and one that consumes the iterator. I know what I want and I'm not looking for any other workaround that you might imagine, even if you have some good ideas :)